# Create chapters with Office

Tags: kindle, pdf, calibre, libreoffice, chapters

I usually create summaries of my university stuff with Open Office (in DIN A5 page format) and export it as a PDF. This file I then just send to my Kindle 4 and the document is ready to be read.

Now I would like to define "location" (i.e. chapters) so that I can easily navigate through my document.
My kindle displays such chapters as little points at the bottom, as can be seen here:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

I already define chapters in my document as "Heading 1" etc., but apparently that doesn't help.

Can Calibre be helpful?

It cannot be exported in any other format, other than PDF, as I use some graphics and formulas, which are displayed corruptly when exporting directly as ODT.

Comment: Are you sure your Kindle shows chapter marks for `.pdf` files? Mine (third generation) only does this for `.mobi` (or `.azw`) files.

Comment: @Tim: No, it shows them for .mobi only. But I'm looking for a way to display them for PDF as well.

Comment: You can't. Better look for a way to create mobi files.

Comment: If you make your pdf from Latex source, then you can have chapters, try this pdf on your kindle as an example : www.promtools.org/prom6/downloads/prom-6.0-getting-started.pdf